# Composer not intalling new libraries

Tags: php, git, composer-php

I'm using Composer along with my PHP project. It was working fine and I had installed a few php libraries from packagist. But after I restarted the server for maintenance reasons, it seems like composer is not working anymore. It is giving me this error when I try to install a library:

> [RuntimeException]
>    Failed to clone `http://github.com/rchouinard/rych-random.git`, git was not
>    found, check that it is installed and in your PATH env.
>
> sh: git: command not found

I `self-updated` it and all other things to fix this problem.

Comment: It's almost as if Git cannot be found, almost as if you created an alias for it, but that alias was lost when you restarted the server.

Comment: Dude, do you not understand that "git: command not found" means that git is not available?

Comment: IMO: this question is too localized

Comment: @Danack i used composer before without installing any git, i thought it may be installed automatically with composer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer install stable packages from the dist, which does not require git.

However, if you have unstable packages in your project composer installs from source (as there is no dist available). To do this, git is needed (except if you use [custom repositories](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories) which are from other sources, like svn)